# Multiple Outbound Calls to Autopilot using Functions - runtime application timed out

Tags: node.js, async-await, twilio

I have about 50-60 outbound calls to make once an hour. I have a Serverless function calling a flow API. The flow api calls a Function. And the function looks like this:

```
const makeCalls = (arr, callbackHandler) => {
    const client = context.getTwilioClient();
    let itemsProcessed = 0;

    arr.forEach(item => {
        client.calls.create({
            url: 'https://channels.autopilot.twilio.com/v1/XXX/XXX/twilio-voice',
            to: item.phone,
            from: 'XXX',
        }, function(err, result) {
            itemsProcessed++;
            if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
            console.log('New phone call started...', result);
        });
    });

    if(itemsProcessed === arr.length) { callbackHandler(); }
};
```

Every time I execute the script, the phone calls go out just fine, but I get a `runtime application timed out` error. How do I fix the issue? What am I missing? (I apologize for the janky async handling).

Comment: which service do you use this serverless? also do you return response at the end of this process?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I put my janky async test in the wrong place. It should have been in the function call that returns the result.